# Неповторяющийся случайный фон

Tags: javascript, html, случайные-числа

Пытаюсь реализовать кнопку, по нажатию на которую должен выставляться случайный фон, да так, чтобы картинки при повторном нажатии не повторялись. Сделал массив с ссылками из тем и клавишу для вывода.
Но функция работает не идеально.

```js
const buttonChangeTheme = document.getElementById('changeTheme');
const body = document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0];
let themes = [
  'url("https://solovey.su/image/download/id=1641&type=original")',
  'url("http://www.hqwallpapers.ru/wallpapers/animals/myshka-s-buketom.jpg")',
  'url("http://www.gandex.ru/upl/oboi/gandex.ru-19837_30bd8502831492b543db9289b08aa491.jpg")',
  'url("http://planetakartinok.net/photo/0-0/9174_1363118876.jpg")',
  'url("http://lookw.ru/1/487/1402241735-oboi-1920h1080.-planeta-obezyan-21.jpg")'
];
let themesAnother = []
let themesAnother1 = new Set(themesAnother);
let difference = [...new Set([...themes].filter(x => !themesAnother1.has(x)))];
//сортировка на уникальный фон
buttonChangeTheme.onclick = function() {
  if (difference.length !== 0) {
    body.style.backgroundImage = difference[Math.floor(Math.random() * (difference.length - 1 + 1)) + 1];
    themesAnother.push(body.style.backgroundImage);
    themes.splice(body.style.backgroundImage - 1, 1);
  }
};
```

```css
body {
  text-align: center;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  background-size: cover
}
```

```html
<input type="button" id="changeTheme" value="Смена темы" />
```

Попытался сделать попроще формулу, для того, чтобы разобраться, где скрывается ошибка, но запутался лишь больше.
Данная функция должна выводить случайный числа из массива, также не повторяясь.
https://jsfiddle.net/Indy660/6d7g9hyk/

```
let themes=[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]
let themesAnother =[]
buttonChangeTheme.onclick = function() {
    if (themes!==0) {
        let fone = themes[Math.floor(Math.random() * (themes.length - 1 + 1)) + 1];
        themesAnother.push(fone);
        themes.splice(fone-1,1);
    } 
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- Оставляем только уникальный набор изображений: [Set](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set).
- Сортируем в случайном порядке единожды: [sort](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort).
- Выбираем первое изображение из массива при смене фонового изображения: [splice](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice).

```js
// Кнопка для изменения фонового изображения.
const BUTTON = document.querySelector('button[name="theme"]');

// Исходный массив с изображениями. `Картинка+4` повторяется трижды.
const SOURCES = [
  'https://via.placeholder.com/960x400/100E17/FFFFFF?text=Картинка+4',
  'https://via.placeholder.com/960x400/9B59B6/FFFFFF?text=Картинка+1',
  'https://via.placeholder.com/960x400/2ECC71/FFFFFF?text=Картинка+2',
  'https://via.placeholder.com/960x400/100E17/FFFFFF?text=Картинка+4',
  'https://via.placeholder.com/960x400/82A43A/FFFFFF?text=Картинка+3',
  'https://via.placeholder.com/960x400/100E17/FFFFFF?text=Картинка+4'
];

// Рабочий массив изображений. Изначально пуст.
let images = [];

// Добавляем функцию обработчик на событие `click`.
BUTTON.addEventListener('click', changeTheme);

// Зададим начальное изображение.
changeTheme();

// Изменить фоновое изображение.
function changeTheme(event) {
  // Если не осталось больше изображений в массиве,
  // подготовим новый рабочий массив.
  if (!images.length) prepareImages();

  // Удаляем первое изображение из массива и
  // берем первое изображение из массива удаленных.
  const [image] = images.splice(0, 1);
  
  // Меняем фоновое изображение.
  document.body.style.backgroundImage = 'url(' + image + ')';

  // Если не осталось больше изображений в массиве, блокируем кнопку.
  // if (!images.length) BUTTON.disabled = true;
}

// Подготовить рабочий массив изображений.
function prepareImages() {
  // Оставим только уникальный набор изображений.
  images = [...new Set(SOURCES)];
  
  // Сортируем единожды в случайном порядке.
  images.sort((a, b) => Math.random() - 0.5);
}
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  background-attachment: fixed;
  background-color: #fafafa;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: top;
  background-size: cover;
}
```

```html
<button type="button" name="theme">Сменить фон</button>
```

---

Метод [splice](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice) удаляет/изменяет элемент из массива и в качестве возвращаемого значения содержит массив из удаленных элементов. Если был удален один элемент, то вернется массив из одного элемента.

---

**UPD** Добавлено зацикливание при показе изображений.

Comment: Да, работает.
За комментарии и фичи отдельное спасибо!

Comment: Единственное, как я понимаю, можно убрать аргумент event из функции changeTheme

Comment: Да, конечно. Это просто привычка маленькая, чтобы было сразу видно, что данная функция вызывается по какому-то событию из слушателя.

Answer (score 1):

```js
const buttonChangeTheme = document.getElementById('changeTheme');
const body = document.querySelector('body'); // берет первый такой элемент
let themes = [
  'https://solovey.su/image/download/id=1641&type=original',
  'http://www.hqwallpapers.ru/wallpapers/animals/myshka-s-buketom.jpg',
  'http://www.gandex.ru/upl/oboi/gandex.ru-19837_30bd8502831492b543db9289b08aa491.jpg',
  //Из-за Совы обос... Убрал её!)
  'http://lookw.ru/1/487/1402241735-oboi-1920h1080.-planeta-obezyan-21.jpg'
];

let prev; // Для хранения номера предыдущей картинки
buttonChangeTheme.addEventListener('click', function(){
  let check = true;
  let index; // Для сохранения случайного числа
  while( check ){
    index = Math.floor( Math.random() * themes.length );
    //Создаем случайное число и как только оно не равно prev - прерываем цикл
    if( index !== prev ) { check = false; }
  }
  
  console.clear(); console.log( 'Предыдущий: ' + prev + ' // Текущий: ' + index );

  body.style.backgroundImage = 'url(' + themes[index] + ')';
  // Легче так, чем в каждом элементе массика указывать про url();
 
  body.style.backgroundColor = `RGB(${Math.random()*200}, ${Math.random()*150}, ${Math.random()*150})`;
  // Случайный фон, если картинки кривые (а они кривые). 
  // Можно также задать массив цветов и переключать их через тот же index

  prev = index; // В конце запоминаем текущий индекс как "предыдущий" для следующего клика
});
```

```css
body {
  background-size: 100vw 100vh;
  background-position: fixed;
}
```

```html
<input type="button" id="changeTheme" value="Смена темы"/>
```

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/Indy660/b1gt20ja/
Проверил на большем кол-ве фотографий (в вопросе дал урезанную версию), к сожалению, выводятся повторяющиеся. Для простоты, оставил старую форму записи массива с темами.
ATTENTION - сова сохранена!

Comment: О_о а задача была в том, чтобы больше одного раза не показывать? (в ответе дан вариант с запретом на повтор два раза подряд... хотя можно докурутить и запрет на N раз подряд)

Comment: Задача была, чтобы при первом цикле показались все фотографии без повторов

Answer (score 0):

Картинки не будет повторяться, если её не будет в массиве.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```js
let bgArr = [
  'https://bipbap.ru/wp-content/uploads/2017/10/0_8eb56_842bba74_XL-640x400.jpg',
  'https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcRgtN5i-ym2j7nhD7L5VY3l2TpjKKDQjp9wqqiGKW-PQCestJgOvQ',
  'https://i.uaportal.com/2019/3/1/3.jpg',
  'https://i.pinimg.com/originals/c6/c4/0d/c6c40d8dd7d307d1b963b28b7af9eafb.jpg',
  'https://i.ytimg.com/vi/aoh6oUhtiyo/maxresdefault.jpg'
];

randomBg(); // запускаем в начале
$('#change').on('click', randomBg); // и при клике

function randomBg() {
  console.clear();
  if (!bgArr || bgArr != '') {
    let random = Math.floor(Math.random() * bgArr.length); // Выбираем рандомный индекс по массиву
    $('body').css('background-image', 'url('+bgArr[random]+')'); // выставляем image для body
    bgArr.splice(random, 1); // удаляем из массива
    console.info('Установлен фон '+random);
  } else console.info('Массив пустой');
}
```

```css
body {
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input id="change" type="button" value="Сменить фон">
```