# Изменение атрибута src изображения при изменении свойства location.hash

Tags: javascript, html

Есть код `<img src="">`, вместо изображения нужно как-то вставить код JS:

```
$(window).bind('hashchange', function() {
  document.write(location.hash.slice(1));
});
```

Сделать это нужно для того, чтобы при добавлении хэша менялось изображение. Если ставлю код как обычный путь к изображению, ничего не работает.

---

Как это сделать?

Comment: По какому принципу это работает? Вы можете писать вопросы более развернуто, "а не есть и как?" Где есть, для каких целей, по какому принципу работать должно, ничего не объясняете, здесь нет экстрасенсов и телепатов.

Comment: Я объяснил максимально подробно. При входе на страницу с определенным хэшем, должно появляться определённое изображение.

Comment: Ну используйте объект `Image` и аттрибут `src`, заносите свой хеш, в чем проблема?

Comment: [document.write](https://learn.javascript.ru/document-write) тут все написано.

Comment: document.write для вывода

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/993822/256824

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно заранее определить какому `hash` будет соответствовать изображение, чтобы не ставить полный путь к изображению в `hash`.

```js
// Объект с изображениями.
var sources = {
  123: 'https://via.placeholder.com/388x188/9B59B6/FFFFFF?text=Изображение+1',
  456: 'https://via.placeholder.com/388x188/2ECC71/FFFFFF?text=Изображение+2',
  789: 'https://via.placeholder.com/388x188/82A43A/FFFFFF?text=Изображение+3',
  1024: 'https://via.placeholder.com/388x188/100E17/FFFFFF?text=Изображение+4'
};

// Данный метод запускается при изменении `hash`.
$(window).on('hashchange', function() {
  // Отрезаем часть `hash`, начиная с индекса 1.
  var part = window.location.hash.slice(1);

  // Если в объекте `sources` есть свойство,
  // соответствующее `hash`.
  if (part in sources) {
    // Выбираем изображение
    // из объекта с изображениями.
    var image = sources[part];

    // Меняем изображение.
    $('img').attr('src', image);

    // Меняем фоновое изображение.
    // $('body').css('background-image', 'url(' + image + ')');
  }
});
```

```html
<a href="#123">Изображение 1</a>
<a href="#456">Изображение 2</a>
<a href="#789">Изображение 3</a>
<a href="#1024">Изображение 4</a>
<a href="#102">Не существующее</a>

<hr>

<img src="https://via.placeholder.com/388x188/9B59B6/FFFFFF?text=Начальное+изображение">

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

---

Либо ставить в `hash` только имя файла, а при изменении `hash` формировать полный путь:

```
// Данный метод запускается при изменении `hash`.
$(window).on('hashchange', function() {
    // Отрезаем часть `hash`, начиная с индекса 1.
    var part = window.location.hash.slice(1);

    // Меняем изображение.
    $('img').attr('src', 'путь/до/изображения/' + part);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

наверное Вы что-то такое ищете? нажмите выполнить несколько раз и увидите разные картинки, основанные на случайном числе

```js
let hash = Math.floor(Math.random()*1111)+1;
img.src = `http://www.gravatar.com/avatar/${hash}?r=PG&s=128&default=identicon`;
```

```html
<img id="img">
```